# Netlogo: Any Pointers on creating a table for a reactive wireless sensor network?

Tags: netlogo

As stated above, I am trying to implement a reactive wireless network, I have set the network up using links between turtles but I am having trouble with how to generate a routing table. At the moment I have tried lists and "tables" but netlogo tables seem to work like dictionaries than what I first imagined a table to be. Can anyone help with something I can look into please? The overall goal is to have each turtle create a table with its neighbours then propegate it out so every turtle will end up merging tables until the whole network topology is created.

Thank you and sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: Your question is so general that it's difficult to offer anything besides very general advice. You may be trying to tackle too much all at once by writing a big program all at once.I would suggest finding some simpler form of the problem you are trying to solve. Solve that, then try to incrementally extend your solution, to get you closer and closer to solving the full problem.